# Smartlink on drone mounted weapons

Tags: combat, shadowrun-sr5

Can I benefit from a Smartgun system if I am jumped in a drone that has a mounted weapon with a smartgun? Does the drone benefit from it when attacking autonomously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SR5, p. 433 in Smart firing platform chapter : You can use an implanted smartlink with the
smartgun if you’re in VR.

I think it's the same for a rigger jumped in a drone, it's VR.